# Any free or cheap soft for video composing

Tags: software-recommendation

anyone knows if there is any video composing software cheap or free like, final cut pro, avid; to work in pair with after effect ?

Comment: Welcome Makamik :) If the link above doesn't solve your issue, please specify what do you want to achieve. Start with the tour: http://video.stackexchange.com/tour to get familiar with this site. Anyway, enjoy video.se!

Comment: Tks, very kind im learning this site slowly ;)

Comment: Note: The only [NLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_editing_system) that's working well with after effects is premiere of course. But every good NLE supports [edit decision lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_decision_list), which is a solid option. Maybe scripting is requiered building some kind of real bridge (pipeline) between the tools, but that's another question :)